# KeyError: 'final_result' when using boxplot

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make boxplot using two features namely-'date_submitted' & 'final_result'.
I have checked the documentation. I don't understand why this error is coming.

I used the following code-

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset cleaned/assessments.csv')

    df.boxplot(column ='date_submitted', by='final_result')
```

this is the description of my dataset-

```
               date_submitted  date_registration  date_unregistration     sum_click  \
count    28785.000000       28785.000000         28785.000000  28785.000000   
mean        26.414139         -69.139552           321.657426      2.660066   
std         15.890933          49.305239           188.935462      5.177789   
min        -11.000000        -322.000000          -317.000000      1.000000   
25%         18.000000        -100.000000           130.000000      1.000000   
50%         24.000000         -56.000000           445.000000      1.000000   
75%         30.000000         -29.000000           445.000000      3.000000   
max        241.000000         124.000000           445.000000    511.000000   

       num_of_prev_attempts      age_band        region  highest_education  \
count          28785.000000  28785.000000  25559.000000       28785.000000   
mean               0.121278      1.693660      5.041981           1.280111   
std                0.420666      0.474206      3.689341           0.769604   
min                0.000000      0.000000      0.000000           0.000000   
25%                0.000000      1.000000      2.000000           1.000000   
50%                0.000000      2.000000      5.000000           1.000000   
75%                0.000000      2.000000      9.000000           2.000000   
max                6.000000      2.000000     11.000000           4.000000   

       studied_credits         score  final_result  
count     28785.000000  28785.000000  28785.000000  
mean         78.691506     75.453431      1.029703  
std          40.617665     19.968919      0.884043  
min          30.000000      0.000000      0.000000  
25%          60.000000     68.000000      0.000000  
50%          60.000000     82.000000      1.000000  
75%         120.000000     87.000000      2.000000  
max         655.000000    100.000000      2.000000
```

error traceback-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/outliers.py", line 6, in <module>
    df.boxplot(column ='date_submitted', by='final_result')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5516, in boxplot
    **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2689, in boxplot
    return_type=return_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 3077, in _grouped_plot_by_column
    grouped = data.groupby(by)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3436, in groupby
    sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1311, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 418, in __init__
    level=level, sort=sort)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2264, in _get_grouper
    in_axis, name, gpr = True, gpr, obj[gpr]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1969, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1976, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1091, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3211, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1759, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3979)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3843)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 668, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12265)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 676, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12216)
KeyError: 'final_result'
[Finished in 0.292s]
```

I don't understand why is this error is showing up.

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: where is that in my post ?

Comment: It is not in your code. He is asking you to execute it and show the result here,.

Comment: I think there are some traling witespaces in column names, what is possible check by `print (df.columns.tolist())`